# wxPython , Button size not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, wxpython

I am using `python 3.6` , `wxPython '4.0.3 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5'` on `Windows 10`. I am trying to set the size of the button but it is not working. The size of frame was changing but not that of the button. The button takes up the whole frame. Here is my code:

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
panel = wx.Panel()
mystyles = wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CAPTION | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX
fra = wx.Frame(panel,title="learning",style=mystyles,size=(200,200))
button = wx.Button(fra,label="Press Me",size=(10,10))
fra.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are creating a frame inside a panel. The normal practise is for the opposite. Try this:

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
mystyles = wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CAPTION | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX
fra = wx.Frame(None, title="learning", style=mystyles, size=(200, 200))
panel = wx.Panel(fra)
button = wx.Button(panel, label="Press Me", size=(10, 10))
fra.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I have also replaced the parent of the button to be the panel.

The `None` in the frame constructor means it is the main window. (If it isn't the main window put the main window as a argument in place of `None`)

Comment: I just started learning it today so i don't know much about it. It is nearly same as `tkinter`. However thanks.

Comment: I am having the same problem, however I don't even create the panel. I only create the frame, and am trying to put the button inside of the frame. However it takes up the whole screen too. Why does this occur?